# Javascript Ajax send complex Mutiple Parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to make an Ajax call with 2 parameters. 1 is DTO and other one is String.

The problem is , it works fine when i send 1 parameter. When i send two parameters, it is not able to  find the proxy method and returns a 404.

This works : 
  dto:

```
loginInfo  = {
                      Email: txtEmail,
            Password: txtPassword           
        };



self.ajaxService({
                url: appSettings.CandidateServiceUrl + "/Login",
                data :JSON.stringify(loginInfo),
                makeBusy: true,
                type: "POST",
```

....

But when i want to add additional parameters, a String, it doesnt work..

`data :{ 'loginInfo': JSON.stringify(loginInfo) , 'SiteName' : 'test' }`,

I tried by Creating a Wrapper DTO that will contain the my dto and string. That works. But i want to send as two methods.

My Proxy method is something like

```
 [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Login(LoginDto dto, string SiteName)
        {
}
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` the whole of the second `data` parameter.

Comment: I tried                `data :{ 'loginInfo': JSON.stringify(loginInfo) , 'SiteName' : JSON.stringify('test') },` But still getting 404.. When i tried to see the request..  `loginInfo={"Email":"abcr@gmail.com","Password":"lkadlkfkjdlkfj"}&SiteName="test"`  Just wondering.. should i stringify the second parameter since it is already a string?

Comment: I didn't mean the second parameter, but the entire `data` attribute: `data : JSON.stringify({ 'loginInfo': JSON.stringify(loginInfo) , 'SiteName' : 'test' })` - you are currently passing it an object

Comment: Great.. i think i am almost close to it.. While this made it go as two seperate objects.. i still get 404 .. The moment i change my controller method to have a wrapper signature.. it works..  when i inspected the fiddler..this is the raw value passed `{"loginInfo":"{\"Email\":\"kjdklf@gmail.com\",\"Password\":\"lkljdflkdsjflk\"}","SiteName":"test"}`   and it works when i change my method signature to  `public HttpResponseMessage Login(WrapperLoginDto dto)` the Wrapper has both Login info and Sitename